# Sequential browsing of an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a system that uses Elasticsearch to store and retrieve library catalogue data. One thing I've been asked for is a browse interface.

Here's a definition of what this is:

- The user does a search, for example "Author starts with" and they
  supply "Smith"
- The system puts them into the middle of a list of authors, at or near
  the position of the first one that starts with "Smith", so they might
  see:

> ```
>     Smart, Murray
>     Smart, Murray J.
>     Smeaton, Duncan
>     Smieliauskas, Wally
>     Smillie, John
>     Smith Milway, Katie <-- this being the first actual search result
>     Smith, A. M. C.
>     Smith, Andrew
>     Smith, Andrew M. C.
>     etc.
> ```

- The one with the marker is the one actually searched for, but you can see the ones around it according to the sort order, *including ones that don't actually match the query.*
- These will be paged, so having ~20 or so results per page. If the user pages back, they head towards the start of the alphabet, if they page forwards they will go onward.
- Each result shown will have a count beside it showing how many results (i.e. catalogue items) are associated with that author.
- Clicking on a result takes you to everything by that author (this and everything beyond it is fairly easy and mostly implemented already.)

I'm wondering if anyone has any good ideas on how to approach this. At this stage, I don't care too much about handling searches that aren't "field starts with" searches, as exactly how that will be done is currently up in the air and I'll deal with it when the time comes.

Here's what I'm thinking, but there are serious issues with it:

- All the fields that are going to be browsed are faceted
- I get a list of all the facets for that field, search through it to find the starting point, and handle the paging manually in code.
- This has the big problem that I might be fetching hundreds of thousands of terms and processing them, which won't be quick.
- In retrospect, it's no different to loading all the values into its own index and fetching all them in sorted order.

I'm open to any options here, whether I can somehow jump into the middle of a large set of facets like the query "from" field, or if I should instead put everything into another index specifically for this purpose (though I don't know how I'd structure and query it), or something else.

From what I can see, my ideal solution would be that I can specify the facet field, tell ES that I want to start at the one that starts with "Smith", and it displays from around there, then I have the ability to say "go 20 back", but I'm not sure that this is possible.

You can see an example of the sort of thing I'm talking about in action here: http://hollisclassic.harvard.edu/ - put in Smith as "Author (last name first)", and it gives you a (terribly ugly looking) browse list.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On:

> The one with the marker is the one actually searched for, but you can
>   see the ones around it according to the sort order, including ones
>   that don't actually match the query.

I had a similar requirement: "Show the user how many records we would have found if the search-conditions were more relaxed".
I solved this by doing two searches (one exact, one more relaxed), as the performance of ES is so good that doing one or two searches does not matter. The time gets eaten up in the displaying (in my case) and not in the search.

Still you would need to merge these two results in you application to generate one list to display.

Comment: How would you relax the search? I suppose you could chop a few letters off, or make it go to a few adjacent letters if it's already of length 1. It might take a couple of iterations if you don't get enough results from an expanded search I suppose.

Comment: In my case relaxing the search meant to leave a facet away (language). But in the case of authors probably leaving a letter or two away would be the right thing. You could do a count only search until you get a significant bigger result set and then do the search again to load the fields. Depends a bit on how much performance you have at hand.